# How to add next and previous buttons on ad (item) view on dj-classifieds (Joomla)?

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla3.0

I tried many codes to do the thing, but it's not working.

The Image code is in the line 21. This is a copy of the code where I have to add the next and previous buttons:

```
<?php

defined ('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$par = JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_djclassifieds' );
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$item = $this->item;
$main_img_width = $par->get('gallery_width','200')-4;
$thumbs_limit = $par->get('gallery_thumbs_in_row','3');
$thumb_width = round(($par->get('gallery_width','200')/$thumbs_limit)-14);
$djMediaTools = ($par->get('djmediatools_integration', 0) == '1' && $par->get('djmediatools_album_item', 0) > 0) ? $par->get('djmediatools_album_item', 0) : false;
$djMediaToolsMinimum = (int)$par->get('djmediatools_minimum', 1);
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
?>

    <div class="images_wrap" style="width:<?php echo $par->get('gallery_width','200');?>px"><div class="images">
        <?php if ($djMediaTools > 0 && count($this->item_images) >= $djMediaToolsMinimum) {?>
            <div class="djc_images">
            <?php echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', '{djmedia '.(int)$djMediaTools.'}', $par, 'com_djclassifieds.item.djmediatools'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="djc_images">
                    <div class="djc_mainimage">
                    <?php if(count($this->item_images)){ ?>
                        <a id="djc_mainimagelink" rel="djc_lb_0" title="<?php echo $item->name; ?>" href="<?php echo JURI::base(true).$this->item_images[0]->thumb_b; ?>">
                            <img id="djc_mainimage" alt="<?php echo $item->name; ?>" src="<?php echo JURI::base(true).$this->item_images[0]->thumb_b;?>" />
                        </a>
                    <?php }else{?>  
                        <?php if($par->get('blank_img_source','0')==1){ ?>
                            <img id="djc_mainimage" class="djc_mainimage_no_image" style="width:<?php echo $par->get('gallery_width','200');?>px" alt="<?php echo $item->name; ?>" src="<?php echo DJClassifiedsImage::getCatImage($item->cat_id);?>" />
                        <?php }else{ ?>
                            <img id="djc_mainimage" class="djc_mainimage_no_image" style="width:<?php echo $par->get('gallery_width','200');?>px" alt="<?php echo $item->name; ?>" src="<?php echo JURI::base(true).$par->get('blank_img_path','/components/com_djclassifieds/assets/images/').'no-image-big.png';?>" />
                        <?php } ?>                                                      
                    <?php }?>   
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    if (count($this->item_images) > 1) { ?>
                        <div class="djc_thumbnails djc_thumbs_gal<?php echo $thumbs_limit;?> " id="djc_thumbnails">
                        <?php foreach($this->item_images as $im=>$img){
                                if($im>0 && $im%$thumbs_limit==0){
                                    $new_row_class = ' new_row';
                                }else{
                                    $new_row_class = '';
                                }
                             ?>
                            <div class="djc_thumbnail djc_thumb_row<?php echo $new_row_class;?>">
                                <a rel="<?php echo JURI::base(true).$img->thumb_b;?>" title="<?php echo $img->caption; ?>" href="<?php echo JURI::base(true).$img->thumb_b;?>">
                                    <img  alt="<?php echo $img->caption; ?>" src="<?php echo JURI::base(true).$img->thumb_s;?>" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <div class="clear_both"></div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php for($ii=0; $ii<count($this->item_images);$ii++ ){ ?>
                        <a id="djc_lb_<?php echo $ii; ?>" class="lightbox-djitem" rel="lightbox-djitem" title="<?php echo $this->item_images[$ii]->caption;?>" href="<?php echo JURI::base(true).$this->item_images[$ii]->thumb_b;?>" style="display: none;"></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>  
            <?php } ?>
            </div></div>            
    <script type="text/javascript">
        this.DJCFImageSwitcher = function (){
            var mainimagelink = document.id('djc_mainimagelink');
            var mainimage = document.id('djc_mainimage');
            var thumbs = document.id('djc_thumbnails') ? document.id('djc_thumbnails').getElements('img') : null;
            var thumblinks = document.id('djc_thumbnails') ? document.id('djc_thumbnails').getElements('a') : null;

            <?php  if($par->get('lightbox_type','slimbox')!='magnific'){ ?>
                if(mainimagelink && mainimage) {
                    mainimagelink.removeEvents('click').addEvent('click', function(evt) {
                        var rel = mainimagelink.rel;
                        document.id(rel).fireEvent('click', document.id(rel));

                        //if(!/android|iphone|ipod|series60|symbian|windows ce|blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                            return false;
                        //}
                        //return true;
                    });
                }
            <?php } ?>

            if (!mainimage || !mainimagelink || !thumblinks || !thumbs) return false;

            thumblinks.each(function(thumblink,index){
                var fx = new Fx.Tween(mainimage, {link: 'cancel', duration: 200});

                thumblink.addEvent('click',function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    //new Event(element).stop();
                    /*
                    mainimage.onload = function() {
                        fx.start('opacity',0,1);
                    };
                    */
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function() {
                        fx.start('opacity',0,1);
                    };

                    fx.start('opacity',1,0).chain(function(){
                        mainimagelink.href = thumblink.href;
                        mainimagelink.title = thumblink.title;
                        mainimagelink.rel = 'djc_lb_'+index;
                        img.src = thumblink.rel;
                        mainimage.src = img.src;
                        mainimage.alt = thumblink.title;
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }; 

        window.addEvent('load', function(){ 
            var img_width = document.id('dj-classifieds').getElement('.djc_images').getSize().x;
            var dj_item = document.id('dj-classifieds').getElement('.djcf_images_generaldet_box').getSize().x;
            var general_det = dj_item-img_width-1; 
            if(general_det<150){
                document.id('dj-classifieds').getElement('.general_det').addClass('general_det_s');
            }       
            if(general_det<301){
                document.id('dj-classifieds').getElement('.general_det').addClass('general_det_m');
            }   
            document.id('dj-classifieds').getElement('.general_det').setStyle('width',general_det) ;        
        });
        window.addEvent('domready', function(){     
            DJCFImageSwitcher();
        });
    </script>               
    <?php  if($par->get('lightbox_type','slimbox')=='magnific'){ ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            !function($){

                $(document).ready(function(){

                    $('#djc_mainimagelink').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
                        console.log(rel);
                        $('#'+rel).click();

                        //console.log(e);
                        //do other stuff when a click happens
                    });


                    $('.lightbox-djitem').magnificPopup({

                        //$(this).magnificPopup({
                           // delegate: '.dj-slide-link', // the selector for gallery item
                            type: 'image',
                            mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
                            gallery: {
                              enabled: true
                            },
                            image: {
                                verticalFit: true,
                                titleSrc: 'title'
                            },
                            iframe: {
                                patterns: {
                                    youtube: null,
                                    vimeo: null,
                                    link: {
                                        index: '/',
                                        src: '%id%'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                       // });
                    });
                });
            }(jQuery);

        </script>               
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: "Not working" is probably not the most informative of fault reports. It may be worth describing how this code is meant to work (what does the JS do - AJAX?) and what issue you are experiencing with it.